# Difference between getServletContext().setInitParameter and getServletContext().setAttribute() in Servlet

Tags: servlets

Is there any difference between getServletContext().setInitParameter and getServletContext().setAttribute() ?

Comment: Yes, there is. One sets init parameters, one sets app context attributes. That they're different is easily testable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they are different, although both have application scope.

Init parameters are set during start-up and can not be changed once start-up has completed.

Context parameters can be set, removed or changed at any point while the application is running.